# How to play videos in pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to play video files depending the select file in this function:

```
    def abrir():
        QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, ("Selecciona los medios"),
                                              os.getcwd(),
                                              ("Video Files (*.avi *.mp4 *.flv)"))
```

My Question is what opcion i have to  use or what module to play video files in pyqt

EDIT:
To play the code of S. Nick I hace to install K lite code

Comment: https://github.com/baoboa/pyqt5/blob/master/examples/multimediawidgets/videowidget.py

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try it:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDir, Qt, QUrl, QSize
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaContent, QMediaPlayer
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QFileDialog, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, 
        QPushButton, QSizePolicy, QSlider, QStyle, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QStatusBar)

class VideoPlayer(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(VideoPlayer, self).__init__(parent)

        self.mediaPlayer = QMediaPlayer(None, QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)

        btnSize = QSize(16, 16)
        videoWidget = QVideoWidget()

        openButton = QPushButton("Open Video")   
        openButton.setToolTip("Open Video File")
        openButton.setStatusTip("Open Video File")
        openButton.setFixedHeight(24)
        openButton.setIconSize(btnSize)
        openButton.setFont(QFont("Noto Sans", 8))
        openButton.setIcon(QIcon.fromTheme("document-open", QIcon("D:/_Qt/img/open.png")))
        openButton.clicked.connect(self.abrir)

        self.playButton = QPushButton()
        self.playButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.playButton.setFixedHeight(24)
        self.playButton.setIconSize(btnSize)
        self.playButton.setIcon(self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MediaPlay))
        self.playButton.clicked.connect(self.play)

        self.positionSlider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal)
        self.positionSlider.setRange(0, 0)
        self.positionSlider.sliderMoved.connect(self.setPosition)

        self.statusBar = QStatusBar()
        self.statusBar.setFont(QFont("Noto Sans", 7))
        self.statusBar.setFixedHeight(14)

        controlLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        controlLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        controlLayout.addWidget(openButton)
        controlLayout.addWidget(self.playButton)
        controlLayout.addWidget(self.positionSlider)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(videoWidget)
        layout.addLayout(controlLayout)
        layout.addWidget(self.statusBar)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(videoWidget)
        self.mediaPlayer.stateChanged.connect(self.mediaStateChanged)
        self.mediaPlayer.positionChanged.connect(self.positionChanged)
        self.mediaPlayer.durationChanged.connect(self.durationChanged)
        self.mediaPlayer.error.connect(self.handleError)
        self.statusBar.showMessage("Ready")

    def abrir(self):
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Selecciona los mediose",
                ".", "Video Files (*.mp4 *.flv *.ts *.mts *.avi)")

        if fileName != '':
            self.mediaPlayer.setMedia(
                    QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile(fileName)))
            self.playButton.setEnabled(True)
            self.statusBar.showMessage(fileName)
            self.play()

    def play(self):
        if self.mediaPlayer.state() == QMediaPlayer.PlayingState:
            self.mediaPlayer.pause()
        else:
            self.mediaPlayer.play()

    def mediaStateChanged(self, state):
        if self.mediaPlayer.state() == QMediaPlayer.PlayingState:
            self.playButton.setIcon(
                    self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MediaPause))
        else:
            self.playButton.setIcon(
                    self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MediaPlay))

    def positionChanged(self, position):
        self.positionSlider.setValue(position)

    def durationChanged(self, duration):
        self.positionSlider.setRange(0, duration)

    def setPosition(self, position):
        self.mediaPlayer.setPosition(position)

    def handleError(self):
        self.playButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.statusBar.showMessage("Error: " + self.mediaPlayer.errorString())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    player = VideoPlayer()
    player.setWindowTitle("Player")
    player.resize(600, 400)
    player.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Can you explain me why is fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Selecciona los mediose",
                ".", "Video Files (*.mp4 *.flv *.ts *.mts *.avi)") and not just fileName=

Comment: @AnimeZero   in `PyQt5` 
static `QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(...)` 
Return type:  `(fileName,  selectedFilter)`

Answer (score 4):

## For PyQt6

I simply convert the @S.Nick answer to PyQt6

```py
from PyQt6.QtGui import QIcon, QFont
from PyQt6.QtCore import QDir, Qt, QUrl, QSize
from PyQt6.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer
from PyQt6.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QFileDialog, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QStyleFactory,
        QPushButton, QSizePolicy, QSlider, QStyle, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QStatusBar)


class VideoPlayer(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(VideoPlayer, self).__init__(parent)

        self.mediaPlayer = QMediaPlayer()

        btnSize = QSize(16, 16)
        videoWidget = QVideoWidget()

        openButton = QPushButton("Open Video")   
        openButton.setToolTip("Open Video File")
        openButton.setStatusTip("Open Video File")
        openButton.setFixedHeight(24)
        openButton.setIconSize(btnSize)
        openButton.setFont(QFont("Noto Sans", 8))
        openButton.setIcon(QIcon.fromTheme("document-open", QIcon("D:/_Qt/img/open.png")))
        openButton.clicked.connect(self.abrir)

        self.playButton = QPushButton()
        self.playButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.playButton.setFixedHeight(24)
        self.playButton.setIconSize(btnSize)
        self.playButton.setIcon(self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.StandardPixmap.SP_MediaPlay))
        self.playButton.clicked.connect(self.play)

        self.positionSlider = QSlider(Qt.Orientation.Horizontal)
        self.positionSlider.setRange(0, 0)
        self.positionSlider.sliderMoved.connect(self.setPosition)

        self.statusBar = QStatusBar()
        self.statusBar.setFont(QFont("Noto Sans", 7))
        self.statusBar.setFixedHeight(14)

        controlLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        controlLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        controlLayout.addWidget(openButton)
        controlLayout.addWidget(self.playButton)
        controlLayout.addWidget(self.positionSlider)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(videoWidget)
        layout.addLayout(controlLayout)
        layout.addWidget(self.statusBar)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        #help(self.mediaPlayer)
        self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(videoWidget)
        self.mediaPlayer.playbackStateChanged.connect(self.mediaStateChanged)
        self.mediaPlayer.positionChanged.connect(self.positionChanged)
        self.mediaPlayer.durationChanged.connect(self.durationChanged)
        self.mediaPlayer.errorChanged.connect(self.handleError)
        self.statusBar.showMessage("Ready")

    def abrir(self):
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Select Media",
                ".", "Video Files (*.mp4 *.flv *.ts *.mts *.avi)")

        if fileName != '':
            self.mediaPlayer.setSource(QUrl.fromLocalFile(fileName))
            self.playButton.setEnabled(True)
            self.statusBar.showMessage(fileName)
            self.play()

    def play(self):
        if self.mediaPlayer.playbackState() == QMediaPlayer.PlaybackState.PlayingState:
            self.mediaPlayer.pause()
        else:
            self.mediaPlayer.play()

    def mediaStateChanged(self, state):
        if self.mediaPlayer.playbackState() == QMediaPlayer.PlaybackState.PlayingState:
            self.playButton.setIcon(
                    self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.StandardPixmap.SP_MediaPause))
        else:
            self.playButton.setIcon(
                    self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.StandardPixmap.SP_MediaPlay))

    def positionChanged(self, position):
        self.positionSlider.setValue(position)

    def durationChanged(self, duration):
        self.positionSlider.setRange(0, duration)

    def setPosition(self, position):
        self.mediaPlayer.setPosition(position)

    def handleError(self):
        self.playButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.statusBar.showMessage("Error: " + self.mediaPlayer.errorString())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    player = VideoPlayer()
    player.setWindowTitle("Player")
    player.resize(900, 600)
    player.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```