# Why media player (pyqt5) is not working on windows 10 - Python

Tags: python, windows, pyqt5

I want to create a videoplayer using mediaplayer in pyqt5 to display mp4 videos ,but it doesn't work for me (I have python 3.6.5 ,pyqt5.14.1 on windows os 10 ). I think that the problem is in windows because I tried the same code with the same version of python and pyqt on windows8 and it's working well.

I used this code [How to play videos in pyqt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842104/how-to-play-videos-in-pyqt)

I got this  with any error (when i run it in IDLE)

[image]

but when I run it in cmd i get this error :

[image]

DirectShowPlayerService :: doRender : Unresolved error code 0x80040266 (IDispatch error #102)

Comment: 1) provide a [mre], 2) Run it from the CMD and indicate if you get any error message.

Comment: @eyllanesc When I run it from CMD i get this error DirectShowPlayerService :: doRender : Unresolved error code 0x80040266 (IDispatch error #102)

Comment: install codecs from http://www.codecguide.com/download_kl.htm